# Gatsby: is there any way to add a prefix path to the assets in develop?

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin

When I launch `gatsby develop` is there any way to tell Gatsby to serve .js and .css files with a relative prefix path?

Why this? Because in my development environment I would like to have (almost) the same configuration I've in prod where I can set assetPrefix and build with --prefix-paths

Comment: Somewhat unsure why you wouldn't declare those files in *gatsby-browser.js*?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [gatsby-plugin-asset-path](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-asset-path/)? It only works when you do a `gatsby build` though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).